# "Must fantasy be stupid?" by Pereslegin

Tags: fantasy-genre, translation

In his essay “[The Back Story to the Last Ring-bearer](http://ymarkov.livejournal.com/273409.html)” Kirill Eskov refers to a work by Pereslegin about errors in fantasy worlds. It sounded interesting, so I followed the link to “[Must fantasy be stupid?](http://www.fantasy.ru/str97/strannik97-talk.html)”, and I saw (as example, the whole text is much, much longer, sorry if you thought it was only that...).

> Мой доклад будет состоять из трех частей. В первой части мы будем исходить из того, что знаем, что такое "фэнтэзи". Во второй части - постараемся определить это понятие. В третьей, увы, мы поймем, почему сделать это невозможно.

Really fascinating, all those Cyrillic letters, *but I cannot read Russian*.

Google Fu did not show a translation. Does have anyone a complete translation? If none exists, can anyone give a short synopsis or even a translation?

Alternatively, if I use a translation program such as Google, Bing, etc., and try to get it as close as possible, is here anyone who is fluent in Russian and could proofread and correct it?

Comment: Google translate; "My report will consist of three parts . In the first part we will obtain from a rigid , that znaem for a definition of " fantasy " . In the second part - postaraemsâ define this notion . In tretʹej , alas , we have no idea, why to do it is impossible ."

Comment: @Richard Yeah, or Babelfish or Bing. But as you see, some words are lost or garbled and it seems to be interesting...perhaps someone has already an English translation I did not find

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer is a simple no. There doesn't seem to be an English translation out there. Noting, obviously that the author is Russian and that the essay was published in Russian in Russia.

Comment: Damn, Russians in Russia are really using Russian...

Comment: And here's me thinking we'd won the Cold War, then all of a sudden *this*. Those sneaky Rooskies.

Comment: Interestingly there are several instances where Russian discoveries were ignored in the West because they were only published in Russian: polywater for example. It is also often a quite different style: I could read some old textbooks from Russian origin after the reunification because they were translated in German for their former satellite, East Germany. You know, imperialistic and capitalistic filth could not be tolerated there....

Comment: @ThorstenS. - There's a reason [polywater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polywater#Background) was ignored, among other reasons being the *so what* factor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ELL , or Russian.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Google Translate had no problem with it:

> My report will consist of three parts. In the first part, we will assume that we know what a "fantasy." In the second part - we will try to define it. The third, unfortunately, we will understand why this is not possible.

Cleaning up the translation, I think the idea is something like this:

> My report will consist of three parts. In the first part, we'll examine the "fantasy" genre by assuming we know what it is. In the second part, we will try to formulate a better definition of fantasy. In the third part, we will examine why, unfortunately, such a definition is impossible.

This fits with the body of the paper: part one talks about errors in fantasy literature, which requires us to assume we know what "fantasy literature" is. The second part attempts to categorize fantasy more precisely. The third attempts to show, from a literary perspective, why a precise definition of "fantasy" can't really work.

(NOTE: I'm not making any judgement for or against these ideas, merely summarizing what they are.)

Comment: Erm, the problem is, if you follow the link...it is a little bit longer than that. I only pasted the first sentences to give the idea that it is cyrillic, the whole essay is a bit longer. Sorry if I gave the wrong impression.

Comment: I used Google translate and got something mostly readable. Translating and posting much more here would be a copyright violation, you'd have to contact the author to see if there is an authorized translation.

Comment: Well, I understand russian and Michael Edenfield translated it very well. It looks like a preface and the Author is just presenting, what his work will consist of. I lost some russian language understanding thru time (I was learning the language in 90's), but still, it's readable (Cyrillic) for me. +1 for Michael Edenfield, please.

Comment: Selected as answer and +1 because you are the only one....